# Gitlab code review batch comments?

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible to get batch comments in Gitlab when doing a code review? Similar to Phabricator, where you only get one email when the reviewer makes multiple comments on your code?

We are trying to use Gitlab at work, and feel kind of spammed by the individual emails per comment.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is now available as per this [news](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/10/22/gitlab-11-4-released/#merge-request-reviews)

Comment: That link doesn't seem to be working anymore

Answer (score 2):

There is an open feature proposal for this [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3364).